# Ensure Maven build fails when tests fail to run

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin, jbehave

I've noticed that sometimes when running maven builds on Jenkins the number of Jbehave tests that are run vary from one run to another. When analyzing the logs I see the following snippet:

```
    Failed to run story stories/cancel.story
java.lang.InterruptedException: stories/cancel.story
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner$RunContext.interruptIfCancelled(StoryRunner.java:616)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runStepsWhileKeepingState(StoryRunner.java:514)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runScenarioSteps(StoryRunner.java:479)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runStepsWithLifecycle(StoryRunner.java:445)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.runCancellable(StoryRunner.java:305)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.run(StoryRunner.java:220)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryRunner.run(StoryRunner.java:181)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:235)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:207)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem is that when tests are skipped or fail to run in this way the build is still considered a success.

Is there a maven surefire plugin configuration that will ensure that whenever tests fail to run the build results in a failure? Here are the maven surefire build configurations

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.thucydides.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-thucydides-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>thucydides-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.17</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>net.thucydides.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-thucydides-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${thucydides.version}</version>
                    </plugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `maven-surefire-plugin` is set to skip tests completely (with `<skip>true</skip>`), so tests are running with `maven-failsafe-plugin`. That plug-in is supposed to not stop on failure during `integration-test`, and then only fail on `verify` phase.

So if you really want this question answered:

> Is there a maven surefire plugin configuration that will ensure that whenever tests fail to run the build results in a failure?

That is: you want `maven-surefire-plugin` to run the tests, and not the `maven-failsafe-plugin`, then the answer is: remove

```
        <configuration>
            <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
```

from your POM. In this case you also don't need `maven-failsafe-plugin` configuration, because it would just make your tests run twice.

But if your goal is to get `maven-failsafe-plugin` to work, then I think you may have one of the following issues:

1. Not running the right goal. As plug-in [help states](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html), you should invoke it as

   ```
   mvn verify
   ```
2. An old plug-in, which is not compatible with test framework you are using (current version is [2.19.1](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html))
3. Or this help recommendation:

   > For very complex builds, it may be better to separate the executions for the integration-test and verify goals:

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.19.1</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>integration-test</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>integration-test</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
       <execution>
         <id>verify</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>verify</goal>
         </goals>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

Comment: I think this could work but what I was looking for was something along the lines of the <systemPropertyVariable><story.timeout.in.secs>3000</story.timeout.in.secs></<systemPropertyVariable>>

Comment: well, since you are using maven-failsafe-plugin, it runs tests generically, not knowing anything about stories, or jbehave in general (from its perspective it's just another JUnit/TestNG test). If you want to pass it as a command line parameter, and you know JBehave can read it, you can do so in `<configuration><argLine>-Dyour.param=...`. But also: did you consider using `jbehave-maven-plugin` to run tests instead of failsafe? it seems has `storyTimeoutInSecs`: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/maven-goals.html